# Eclipse shows an error when Maven builds just fine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am playing with some new Java 8 stream features. But I am having an odd problem with the example code below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class TwoDArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> row1 = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        row1.add("11");
        row1.add("12");
        ArrayList<String> row2 = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        row2.add("21");
        row2.add("22");
        matrix.add(row1);
        matrix.add(row2);
        String[][] array = toArray(matrix, String[]::new, String[][]::new);
        for (String[] row : array) {
            for (String s : row) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static String[][] toArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix,
            IntFunction<String[]> arrayCreator, IntFunction<String[][]> doubleCreator) {
        String[][] array = matrix.stream()
                .map(row -> row.stream().toArray(arrayCreator))
                .toArray(doubleCreator);
        return array;
    }
}
```

I can build it just fine with maven on the commandline, but Eclipse keeps showing an error with the line `.toArray(doubleCreator)` saying

```
The method toArray(IntFunction<A[]>) in the type Stream<String[]> is not
applicable for the arguments (IntFunction<String[][]>)
```

Oddly I can even run the application from eclipse once build with maven. The code is part of a project which I have imported into Eclipse as a maven project. I have tried to make sure that Eclipse and the commandline maven uses the same versions of java and maven, but the problem persists. I am using Eclipse Oxygen, maven 3.5.0 and java 1.8.0_121.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Tips: go to project properties => java compiler => check if java1.8 is in use

Comment: Usually Eclipse uses JDT compiler, instead of Javac. That might explain the difference

Comment: @TuyenNguyen the 1.8 is in use